# Hibernate last record in group using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a table with the following fields: `ID (unique),type, value and createddate`

the data types are uniqueidentifier,varchar and datetime respectively.

sample data:

```
ID   type  value createddate

ui1 field1 value1 2016-02-13 16:39:21.100

ui2 field1 value2 2016-02-20 18:00:00.100

ui3  field2 value3 2016-02-13 16:39:21.200

ui4  field2 value4 2016-02-20 18:00:00.200
```

I need to retrieve the latest value record for each type.

Hence the expected result should be like this:

```
ID  type value createddate

ui2  field1 value2 2016-02-20 18:00:00.100

ui4  field2 value4 2016-02-20 18:00:00.200
```

I hope to carry out the sql query. I need hsql code to achieve this?

Comment: in the sql, u can achieve using join , group by , but hw can we achieve  in hibernate query

Comment: You can do join and group by in HSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HQL query like this

```
FROM Record r 
GROUP BY r.type 
HAVING r.createdDate >= ALL (
    SELECT r2.createdDate 
    FROM Record r2 
    WHERE r2.type = r.type
)
```